# Bonobo Git Server UI is unapplicable

Tags: git, bonobo

This Bonobo server version is 6.3.0.

I did everything: IIS, IIS_IUSRS rights to the App_Data folder, etc.

But why isn't the UI applied?

[image: Bonobo server UI missing]

What's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Check with a browser debugger (Chrome dev tools for instance) what exact file is missing.

In your case, it could be a CSS or theme problem (as in [Bonobo-Git-Server issue 139](https://github.com/jakubgarfield/Bonobo-Git-Server/issues/139))

- check that IIS->WWWS->Common HTTP Features had Static Content ticked,
- Edit `web.config` found in the root of the project, with `compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5"` (this is from 2014, so the targetFramework version might have changed)

Answer (score 0):

Bonobo Git Server doesn’t serve CSS
This is a common issue for Windows 8 users, please see the topic. The solution is simple:

Go to Turn windows features on or off screen
Navigate IS -> WWWS -> Common HTTP Features
**Tick Static Content**